# Extraer Datos CFDI XML en VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, xml

Estoy realizando un programa en donde extraigo datos de un archivo XML y los almaceno en un listView, el problema radica en que si encuentra más de 1 atributo tengo que repetir el valor del elemento en la siguiente fila o dejarlo en blanco.

Anexo mi código, en la que funciona a la perfección si solo encuentra un atributo en el elemento.

```
Try
        Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
        Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
        Dim m_nodelist1 As XmlNodeList
        Dim m_node As XmlNode

        'Creamos el "XML Document"
        m_xmld = New XmlDocument()

        'Cargamos el archivo
        m_xmld.Load(Trim(txtDirectorio.Text))

        'Obtenemos la lista de los nodos "name"
        m_nodelist = m_xmld.GetElementsByTagName("cfdi:InformacionAduanera")
        m_nodelist1 = m_xmld.GetElementsByTagName("cfdi:Concepto")

        'Recorrer XML sacar más de un NoIdentificacion
        For Each m_node In m_nodelist1
            lvNoIdentificacion.Items.Add(m_node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("NoIdentificacion").Value)
        Next

        'Recorrer XML sacar más de un NumeroPedimento
        For Each m_node In m_nodelist
            lvNumeroPedimento.Items.Add(m_node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("NumeroPedimento").Value)
        Next

        'Recorrer los item de la lista 
        'Verificar que contenga 15 digitos el NumeroPedimento (Length=21 por los espacios en blanco entre grupos de digitos)
        'Si el NumeroPedimento no contiene cadena de 15 digitos entonces pintar color Rojo.
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To lvNumeroPedimento.Items.Count - 1
            If lvNumeroPedimento.Items(i).Text.Length <> 21 Then
                lvNumeroPedimento.Items.Item(i).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            Else
                lvNumeroPedimento.Items.Item(i).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
```

El XML está estructurado de la siguiente manera

```
<cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="43223300" NoIdentificacion="AX101100" Cantidad="4" ClaveUnidad="KT" Unidad="kit" Descripcion="Kit Separador de Fibra en campo P/6 Fibras" ValorUnitario="612.00" Importe="2448.00" Descuento="678.34">
        <cfdi:Impuestos>
            <cfdi:Traslados>
                <cfdi:Traslado Base="1769.66" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="283.15" />
            </cfdi:Traslados>
        </cfdi:Impuestos>
        <cfdi:InformacionAduanera NumeroPedimento="XX  XX  38XX  4XX1254" />
        <cfdi:InformacionAduanera NumeroPedimento="XX  XX  38XX  400XX41" />
    </cfdi:Concepto>
```

Anexo una captura para ver si me pueden orientar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con este código logré resolver mi problema, por si alguien le sirve.

```
Try
        Dim doc As XmlDocument
        Dim concepto As XmlNodeList
        Dim Elemento As XmlNode
        Dim subnodo As XmlElement

        ' Creamos el "XML Document"
        doc = New XmlDocument()

        'Cargamos el archivo
        doc.Load(Trim(txtDirectorio.Text))

        'Obtenemos la lista de los nodos "cfdi:Concepto"
        concepto = doc.GetElementsByTagName("cfdi:Concepto")

        'Recorrer XML sacar más de un NoIdentificacion
        For Each Elemento In concepto
            Dim cadena As String
            For Each subnodo In Elemento

                cadena = Trim(subnodo.GetAttribute("NumeroPedimento"))
                If cadena.Length = 0 Then
                Else
                    lvNumeroPedimento.Items.Add(cadena)
                    lvNoIdentificacion.Items.Add(Elemento.Attributes.GetNamedItem("NoIdentificacion").Value)
                    lvCantidad.Items.Add(Elemento.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Cantidad").Value)
                End If
            Next

            If cadena.Length = 0 Then
            Else
                lvNoIdentificacion.Items.Add("------------------------------")
                lvCantidad.Items.Add("----------")
                lvNumeroPedimento.Items.Add("-------------------------------")
            End If
        Next

        'Recorrer los item de la lista 
        'Verificar que contenga 15 digitos el NumeroPedimento (Length=21 por los espacios en blanco entre grupos de digitos)
        'Si el NumeroPedimento no contiene cadena de 15 digitos entonces pintar color Rojo.
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To lvNumeroPedimento.Items.Count - 1
            If lvNumeroPedimento.Items(i).Text.Length <> 21 Then
                lvNumeroPedimento.Items.Item(i).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
                lvCantidad.Items.Item(i).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
                lvNoIdentificacion.Items.Item(i).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            Else
                lvNumeroPedimento.Items.Item(i).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
            End If

            If lvNumeroPedimento.Items(i).Text = "-------------------------------" Then
                lvNumeroPedimento.Items.Item(i).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
                lvNoIdentificacion.Items.Item(i).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
                lvCantidad.Items.Item(i).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

La imagen de como quedó:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]